# ReactJS componentDidMount does not produce the value before rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code and getting the values through the api and set to the state variable but the view is rendered before setting the value to the state. So i could not display the value in my view. How could i change the code to work fine?

```
this.state = {
            activeJobs: [],
            isLoading: true
        };

componentDidMount(){

    axios.get(this.state.url+'/tables')
     .then(response => {
         // If request is good...
         const isLoading = true,
                activeJobs = response.data.activeJobs;
         this.setState({ activeJobs });
      })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log('error ' + error);
      });
}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.activeJobs)
    <p className="text">{!this.state.isLoading && this.state.activeJobs.count} Jobs</p>
}
```

The console i have given inside the render shows blank array. I also tried by changing the function `componentDidMount()` to `componentWillMount()` but getting the same result.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to ensure that an async request will complete before rendering. You can display proper messages in render to reflect the status of the request.

For example - before calling axios, set the state to 'in process' or 'loading', so that render will show an appropriate message. Then, when loading finished successfully or with an error, set the state appropriately to render an appropriate message in the error case, and the result otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't render yet, then simply return `null`:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.activeJobs && !this.state.isLoading) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            { this.state.isLoading && <p className="text">Loading...</p> }
            { !this.state.isLoading && <p className="test">{ this.state.activeJobs.count } Jobs</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In order to set `isLoading`, set it *before* the HTTP call:

```
componentDidMount(){

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    axios.get(this.state.url+'/tables')
     .then(response => {
         // If request is good...
         const activeJobs = response.data.activeJobs;
         this.setState({ activeJobs, isLoading: false });
      })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log('error ' + error);
      });
}
```

Comment: Give a Man a Fish, and You Feed Him for a Day. Teach a Man To Fish, and You Feed Him for a Lifetime :)